# Remove top activity from stack android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am on activity A then I start Activity B from A. Now I am on activity B and starting activity C from B. While starting activity C, I want to remove both Activities A and B. 
I tried this way,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class); //I'm on Activity B, moving to C
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //this should remove the Activity A
startActivity(intent);
finish(); //Finishes activity B
```

My concern to do this, when my activity C started, and I press back, app should be exit. Currently its showing me Activity A.

Comment: can you post the code about how you are moving from A to B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it this way. You need to `finish()` A when starting C. My favorite way of doing this is as follows:

In B, when you want to start C, do it this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class); //Return to the root activity: A
intent.putExtra("launchActivityC", true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //this will clear the entire task stack and create a new instance of A
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the entire task stack (ie: finish activity B and A) and create a new instance of activity A.

Now, in `onCreate()` of activity A, do this (after calling `super.onCreate()`):

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("launchActivityC")) {
    // User wants to launch C now and finish A
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return; // Return immediately so we don't continue with the rest of the onCreate...
}
```

What you are doing is using your root activity, A, as a kind of "dispatcher".

Answer (score 1):

You can add flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in intent to remove top activity.

Example code is given below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

please add  `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);` to remove your stack history also.

Comment: This won't help. A is still in the activity stack. Adding an additional flag when launching C just means that C won't end up in the history. This probably isn't what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(activityContext, ActivityName.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This won't work unless the taskAffinity of activity A and activity C are different. By default they are the same. If this really did work the user would end up with 2 tasks, one containing A and one containing C, so that the BACK key would still take the user from C to A. Not only that, if the user pressed HOME, he would see 2 tasks in the application. This is a mess, and not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add this flag before starting your new activity

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```

This will clear the Activity from top of the stack