# Ghost activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

My application works as follow:

On start I have some `AppStartActivity` which does something, finishes itself and starts `MainActivity` if user is logged in or `LoginActivity` otherwise.

`LoginActivity` finishes itself and starts `MainActivity` when user log in successfully.

On `MainActivity` I have `SomeActivity` from which user can logout. Activity stack for this situation is `MainActivity > SomeActivity`. It is correct, back button works well. When user click `LogOut` button there is a problem. I need to show `LoginActivity` but I don't want to have `MainActivity` and `SomeActivity` on activity stack anymore.

I could resolve this problem if I wouldn't finish `AppStartActivity`. I could go back then with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and it would work well. But here is a problem with back button. I don't want user to come back to this activity with back button. I want it to exit app instead.

UPDATED:

Flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` would be best, but I need it working in API level 9.

Comment: You can finish the MainActivity when you go to SomeActivity and override the onBackPressed method in the SomeActivity to start the MainActivity again. If press LogOut, you can simply finish(); your SomeActivity and start LoginActivity again.

Comment: There are many more activities starting in some order from `MainActivity`.

Comment: Only finish MainActivity when SomeActivity needs to start. Back behavior for the others will be default.

Comment: `SomeActivity` can be started from other activities.

Comment: Maybe, a redesign of your application flow is the way to go. Beautiful code results in beautiful apps.

Comment: Similar question someone asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858108/remove-top-activity-from-stack-android/19858345#19858345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user wants to logout, you just launch `MainActivity` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and pass it an extra in the `Intent` that tells `MainActivity` that the user logged out. `MainActivity` can then immediately launch `LoginActivity` and finish itself.

See my answer to [Remove top activity from stack android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858108/remove-top-activity-from-stack-android/19858345#19858345) for more details about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only missing `finish()` in `SomeActivity` if I understand you correctly.

> stack for this situation is MainActivity > SomeActivity

Click `LogoutButton`

```
onClick(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(SomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITIY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

> > stack for this situation is LoginActivity

Click "Back" `Button` exits app

Comment: It is not that simple. I also need to finish `MainActivity` on this special case.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. You need the `finish()` method of `MainActivity` to run only when logout `Button` is pressed in `SomeActivity` or you just need it cleared off the stack? It sounded like you just need the stack cleared...

Comment: Yes, I need whole stack cleared before starting `LoginActivity`

Comment: And I need it working in API level 9 (`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` need 11)

Comment: Then I fail to see why this code won't work. After running it, the only `Activity` on the stack should be `LoginActivity`

Comment: It may not work if `LoginActivity` is finished. Is there a reason you can't leave that on the stack?

Comment: I don't want back button to go back to this Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The general technique is to use a `BroadcastReceiver` and broadcast to all your activities "hey, please finish() since the user is logging out". This clears your activity stack and prevents the user back pressing to 'logged in' sections of your app.

See [On logout, clear Activity history stack, preventing "back" button from opening logged-in-only Activites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l) for more info.